# Query all posts of a custom taxonomy term

Tags: php, posts, functions, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am using this code on `single.php`, This query working well but when post has parent term (that parent also have child terms) this give output `all posts of parent & children`

But in this condition I want it to query only parent term posts.

```
<?php 
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'serial', array('fields'=>'ids'));
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'serial',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $post_terms,
                ),
        )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            the_title();
        }
    } else {
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

How to query posts according to attached term, Only attached term (not to check for child terms when post have parent term)?

Comment: Just wanted to say that you should use `'field' => 'term_id'` in tax_query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with understanding the nature of posts' hierarchy vs pages' hierarchy.  A page is a type of "post". It can have hierarchical structure.

Posts, by default, do not have hierarchy. So, you would not be able to get post-parents without their children, because the system does not recognize a hierarchy.  This is true unless you modify the structure with a custom function, or install a specific plugin to add hierarchical structure to Posts.

If you really need that hierarchy, you could try [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750931/wordpress-how-to-add-hierarchy-to-posts#40261005) to add a hierarchy. This will permit what you are trying to accomplish.